# How to have choices for multiple slash command arguments Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord.py slash command that takes in two arguments. I wanted to provide choices for these arguments but I can't figure out how.

This is what I have so far but its not working.

```py
    import discord
    from discord import app_commands
    from discord.ext import commands

    @bot.tree.command(name="schedule")
    @app_commands.Argument(name="name", required=True, choices=[])
    @app_commands.Argument(name="day", required=True, choices=[], default="Today")
    async def schedule(interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str, day: str):

        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{name} and {day}")
```

Comment: Your code is not properly indented. Is this part of the problem, or did you not indent properly in post?

Comment: Its indented properly. It probably just got messed up when I made this post. 

I can return the arguments without options but I need to add the options for an api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@discord.app_commands.choices()` gives the command user options to choose from.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="schedule")
@app_commands.choices(name=[
    app_commands.Choice(name='Name 1', value=1),
    app_commands.Choice(name='Name 2', value=2)
])
@app_commands.choices(day=[
    app_commands.Choice(name='Monday', value=1),
    app_commands.Choice(name='Tuesday', value=2)
])
async def schedule(interaction: discord.Interaction, name: app_commands.Choice[int], day: app_commands.Choice[int]):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{name.name} and {day.name}")
```

The type `str` or `int` referenced in `app_commands.Choice[int]` indicates the choice value. Just like how you can get the choice name with `day.name`, you can do the same to get the value; `day.value`.

This is also not the only way to provide choices to a command.

> There are two more ergonomic ways of doing this.

The first one is to use a [typing.Literal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) annotation

```
from typing import Literal

@bot.tree.command(name="schedule")
async def schedule(interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str, day: Literal["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]):
    ...
```

The second way is to use [enum.Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum)

```
class Days(enum.Enum):
    monday = 1
    tuesday = 2
    wednesday = 3

@bot.tree.command(name="schedule")
async def schedule(interaction: discord.Interaction, name: str, day: Days):
    ...
```

Reference: [discord.app_commands.choices](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.choices)